# Could The Borg assimilate a changeling?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, borg

I was curious whether The Borg had ever encountered Odo's species, and would be possible to assimilate them?

Comment: Apologies. I searched for changelings under the `borg` tag, and nothing came up.

Comment: np they used their other name the founders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not on screen no, but in the novel [Lesser Evil](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Lesser_Evil). It's mentioned that

> The unique nature of the species meant that were were resistant to
>   Borg assimilation. A Changeling was simply able to compress themselves
>   and eject any nanoprobes within herself without any ill effects to
>   them being seen.

([Memory beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Changeling), Changeling)